# Python Pandas: if date1 == 0, copy from date2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two date fields (JDRDT and JDCKDT) and at times there is a 0 in JDCKDT. I want to find those and copy the date from JDRDT to this field.

My question is how to do this?

Example:

```
Index   JDCKDT   JDCKDT
10994   19991231      0
11147   19991231      0
```

I want to change it to

```
10994   19991231  19991231
11147   19991231  19991231
```

Comment: pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2],df.iloc[:,[2]]],1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['JDCKDT'] = np.where(df['JDCKDT']==0, df['JDRDT'], df['JDCKDT'])
```

Comment: See below I have provided a much simpler solution: `df.loc[df[2]==0, 2]=df[1]`. Replace 1 & 2 with your column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line of code:

```
Df.JDCKDT=Df.iloc[Df.JDRDT ==0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[10994, 19991231, 0], [11147, 19991231, 2], [12000, 19991232, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    0       1           2
0   10994   19991231    0
1   11147   19991231    2
2   12000   19991232    0

df.loc[df[2]==0, 2]=df[1]

    0       1           2
0   10994   19991231    19991231
1   11147   19991231    2
2   12000   19991232    19991232
```

Replace 1 & 2 with your column names.